# I need an ellipse with semi-axes irrational measures. How to proceed?

Tags: tikz-pgf

```
\documentclass[border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc} %calculos no ambiente tikz
\begin{document}


    %ok
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) ellipse (2 and 1);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    %ok
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) ellipse (2 and 1/2);
    \end{tikzpicture}

    % no ok 
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) ellipse (2 and $\sqrt{2}$);
    \end{tikzpicture}

    %no ok
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) ellipse (2 and $sqrt(2)$);
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @percusse Could you post this comment as answer? Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The dollar characters turn on the TeX *typesetting*. They are not parsed as actual math expressions hence you need to remove them.

Instead you need braces to hide the closing parenthesis such that TikZ don't think it is the end of the coordinate/radius expression.

```
\draw (0,0) ellipse (2 and {sqrt(2)});
```